# Vacuum Tank Emptying Transient Equation

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics

I am trying to derive the differential equation for pulling vacuum on an air tank.

The solution to the ODE:

$$P(t)=P_2 \cdot exp(\frac{dV}{dt} \cdot \frac{t}{V_s})$$
Where $\frac{dV}{dt}$=
flow rate out of tank in ACFM (assuming constant for all time t),
t = time in minutes,
$V_s$ = tank volume in cubic feet, $P_2$
= final pressure, $P_1$
= pressure at time t

Assumptions: ideal gas, constant gas flow rate

My derivation begins with writing the following differential equation:

$$dP=P(1−\frac{dV}{V_s})$$

How do I get to the solution from this?

Comment: And this has never been done before?

Comment: I had an application come up where I work...the vacuum pump manufacturer had this equation  in their catalog. I could not find a derivation for this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get the same result but started from this:

$$\frac{dP}{ P } = (\frac{dV}{dt} / Vs) * dt$$
Then integrating both sides
$$ ∫\frac{1}{P} dP = ∫ (\frac{dV}{dt} / Vs) * dt$$

Integrating:

$$ln|P| = (\frac{dV}{dt} / Vs) * t  + C1$$
Now, we'll exponentiate both sides:

$$P = exp((\frac{dV}{dt} / Vs) * t  + C1)$$ we drop the absolute value for P: it's always positive.

Combine the constants C1 and exp(C1) into one constant, let's call it C:

$$P = C * exp((\frac{dV}{dt} / Vs) * t )$$

This is your answer by replacing C with its boundary value which is $P_2$.

$$P = P_2 * exp((\frac{dV}{dt} / Vs) * t )$$

Comment: I see that my initial equation was wrong... thanks